# Tmux 1.8: How can I use scrolling and mouse-select-pane at the same time?

Tags: ubuntu, tmux

If I set mouse-select-pane, I am able to select pane with mouse, but I can no longer scroll with my mouse within program like less and man like before.

How to solve this?

I am using ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

In Tmux 1.8 if you're on Mac OSX and use Terminal.app, you have got to do one of the following to enable mouse scrolling

1. Use EasySIMBL, please check [this blog by David Verhasselt](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/enable-mouse-support-in-tmux-on-os-x/).
2. Switch to iTerm2.

However, in OS X 10.11, mouse scroll in Terminal.app should work properly with just `#set -g mode-mouse on`.

Note that the latest version of Tmux is now 2.1, so you should consider upgrading it. There will be scrolling problem in tmux 2.1, but you can try to solve it following [this repo](https://github.com/NHDaly/tmux-scroll-copy-mode).

Comment: The original question clearly states that the user is using Ubuntu

Comment: If you spent some time checking what might the original question before edited be, you would not have to reply my answer. And well, I didn't see his edited version so I did not reply him. :)